# Error integrating firebase into react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error when trying to build my react app. The only thing that has changed since the build broke is me trying to add a firebase db to the app. I'm trying to implement it in the same way that I found on a tutorial I'm using.

```
×
REBASE: Rebase.createClass failed. Expected an initialized firebase or firestore database object.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/base.js
C:/Dev/React/my-app/src/base.js:3
  1 | import Rebase from 're-base';
  2 | 
> 3 | const base = Rebase.createClass({
  4 |   apiKey: "AIzaSyC1UGLssKKLkKvYRp02zYVpM1-D88czp7I",
  5 |   authDomain: "catch-of-the-day-ethan-fie.firebaseapp.com",
  6 |   databaseURL: "https://catch-of-the-day-ethan-fie.firebaseio.com",
```

Code from base.js below, personal information and API key redacted:

```
import Rebase from 're-base';

const base = Rebase.createClass({
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx",
  storageBucket: "catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com",
});

export default base;
```

Comment: Please check this guidelines and see if you are doing it right.
https://coderjourney.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-react-with-firebase/

Comment: This worked. It appears I was using syntax from version 2 of the re-base library.

Comment: Good to know it helped to resolve the problem. Please mark my posted answer as correct and helpful answer, for others to know, having similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this guidelines in order to resolve the problem.

https://coderjourney.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-react-with-firebase/

Make sure you are using correct library version syntax as mentioned in above reference.

Answer (score 3):

here you go

```
import Rebase from 're-base'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx",
  storageBucket: "catch-of-the-day-xxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SOME_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID"
}

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database())


export default base;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work:

```
var Rebase = require('re-base');
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
var database = require('firebase/database');
var app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});
var db = firebase.database(app);
var base = Rebase.createClass(db);
```